# MS Word - Changing Margins for Selected Text Forces a Section Break and Restart Page Numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document with an appendix.  I have some large figures in the appendix, so I would like to increase the margins to get as much space as possible.  However, when I do that, it forces a new section and restarts page numbering.  When I edit the header and select "Link to Previous" in an attempt to at least continue page numbers, it changes *all the previous pages* to have the smaller margins.  Deleting the section break has similar effects.

Could it possibly have something to do with headings (not page *headers*) tied to a table of contents?  That is the only thing I can think of - I've been able to modify the margins of a single page in other test documents without affecting sections.

Looking at [these screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB0vQ.jpg), could anyone explain why Word is behaving like this, and how to make it not.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. There is something about the document that you're not describing in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word margins are an attribute of a section, you can't have different margins for pages within the same section (except for the gutter). *See* https://www.asaporg.com/category/office-and-digital-technologies/understanding-sections-in-microsoft-word As a result, you have to have a section break that starts a new page.

Perhaps you could try not changing the margins but rather expanding the indentation of the paragraphs (indentation is an attribute of a paragraph, and can be negative; with indentations you can have text outside the page "margins"). That would give more room on your pages for text, but without having to mess with the margins.

Even with a new section, page numbers should continue unless you've explicitly set them to restart. Try putting your cursor in the header by the page number, and going to the Insert Tab > Header & Footer > Page Number > Format Page Numbers .... From there, make sure that "Continue from previous section" is selected instead of "Start At: ___".